# Using ResolveUrl on HTML button in MasterPage

Tags: asp.net, onclick, resolveurl

I have the following HTML in my MasterPage:

```
<input class="button" type="button" value="Select User" onclick='<%# string.Format(@"location.href={0}", ResolveUrl("~/SelectUser.aspx")) %>' />
```

I'm trying to figure out how to get ResolveUrl to work with an HTML input button, but no matter how I twist and turn it I can't get it right (meaning the click never redirects the page to SelectUser.aspx). I could use an ASP.NET Button, but then I'd have to monkey with my CSS and I really don't want to spend the time doing that.

Any help on how to go about doing this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Look at the rendered JavaScript; it's invalid

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use href like below and make sure that there is no runat="server" tag.

```
    href = "<%=this.ResolveUrl("~/abc.aspx")%>"
```

Answer (score 1):

Either use an ASP.NET `Button` or make it `runat"=server"`.

[The Forgotten Controls: HTML Server Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478973.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

ResolveUrl will only work if you call Page.DataBind() in your Page_Load